# Finding and printing file name of zero length files in python

Tags: python, module, operating-system

I'm learning about the os module and I need to work out to print the file names of only zero length files and the count.

So far I've figured the easiest way to do it is to generate a list or a tuple of files and their sizes in this format:

((zerotextfile1.txt, 0), (notazerotextfile.txt, 15))

Then use an if statement to only print out only files with zero length.

Then use a sum function to add the number of list items to get the count of zero length files.

So far, I've got bits and pieces - it's how to put them together I'm having trouble with.

Some of my bits (viable code I've managed to write, not much, I know):

```
import os
place = 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\Python Programs\\'
for files in os.walk(place):
    print (files)
```

Then there is stuff like os.path.getsize() which requires I put in a filename, so I figure I've got to use a for loop to print a list of the file names in this function in order to get it to work, right?

Any tips or pointing in the right direction would be vastly appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by zero length? Is it zero size?

Comment: yes. i'm guessing that's what my professor meant.

Comment: meaning this was some sort of a homework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os
place = 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\Python Programs\\'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(place):
    for f in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, f) #Full path to the file
        size = os.path.getsize(file_path) #pass the full path to getsize()
        if size == 0:
            print f, file_path
```

Comment: Thank you very much! So you can put a for loop in a for loop...I gotta remember that one. I'll work out the count and sum part, it shouldn't be too hard now.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for the following ?

```
import os
place = 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\Python Programs\\'
for files in os.walk(place):
    if os.path.getsize(b[0] + '\\' +b[2][0]) == 0:
        print (files)
```

Comment: it didn't work. is it because i've already defined files and saying b = files makes it invalid? i totally understand this method, it's list comprehension right?