# finding images in html source code with python

Tags: python, html, regex, python-3.x

I've got to find the images in a html source code. I'm using regex instead of html.parser because I know it better, but if you can explain to me how to use html parsing like you would a child, I'll be happy to go down that road too.

Can't use beautifulsoup, wish I could, but I got to learn to do this the hard way.

I've read through a lot of questions and answers on here on regex and html ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)) so I'm aware of the feelings on this topic.

But hear me out!

Here's my coding attempt (Python 3):

```
import urllib.request
import re

website = urllib.request.urlopen('http://google.com')
html = website.read()
pat = re.compile (r'<img [^>]*src="([^"]+)')
img = pat.findall(html)
```

I double checked my regex on regex101.com and it works at finding the img link, but when I run it on IDLE, I get a syntax error and keeps highlighting the caret. Why?

I'm headed in the right direction... yes?

update:
Hi, I was thinking may be I get short quick answer, but it seems I may touched a nerve in the community.

I am definitely new and terrible at programming, no way around that. I've been reading all the comments and I really appreciate all the help and patience users have shown me.

Comment: well in this context, it means more familiar. i only got thrown html parsing by my teacher and no working examples. got any leads to point me to?

Comment: @user2799617 He's a newbie. Please try to be a bit more civil. From the looks of things you know nothing about proper netiquette.

Comment: You're getting a syntax error because... this is invalid syntax (hint: `re.compile` expects a string). But you should just take a look at the BeautifulSoup html parser, there's enough examples on here and elsewhere that should get you started.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that this is mostly correct code. The regex is giving me a headache, but I'm been trying to teach myself html.parsing and that gave me a headache too. I don't know that damn caret keeps getting called out...

Comment: okay, here is a question...how do i do that? i downloaded it, but my computer looked at the .gz and went "da fuq??" so I figured I'm really close...seriously, i know nothing better. it's just me and idle and a badly written python text book.

Comment: @user2799617 The person has asked a valid question, showed us what he's tried, and checked it on regex101 (which we need a link of). I highly doubt that he has done _anything_ wrong.

Comment: Persons parsing HTML with a regex are _always_ doing something wrong.

Comment: @pythonintraining For the gz issue, I guess you're using Windows. Install a utility like 7Zip.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/nW1aO8

Comment: @user2799617 [Not always](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/1424875).

Comment: hey user2799617, you don't need to ride me, i already ride myself hard enough. i thought the point of stackoverflow was to help people like me, go to reddit or craigslist if you want to keep on ranting.

Comment: "That's mostly correct code" - except for the thing you're trying to pass to `re.compile`. Which should be a string. But isn't. Thus it's invalid syntax, as python doesn't know what it's supposed to be (it highlights the caret, because the partial expression before that could have been a valid term). That's about as patient as I can explain this... you know what a string is, right? @GamesBrainiac not doing research and basic debugging could still be considered doing something wrong. Just looking at examples of `re.compile` and how they differ from his code would have probably helped him...

Comment: Well to start off with, your string needs to be quoted `re.compile (r'<img [^>]*src="([^"]+)')`

Comment: @l4mpi Perhaps he's using something as trivial as notepad++ or perhaps he's now understand where he's going wrong. Perhaps he's confused the `r` infront of a string with regex when its actually raw. There are tonnes of places when a person can mess up. We _need_ to be considerate of newbies.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac First of all, "we" don't "need" to do anything. I agree there's no need to flame or harrass someone who's new, but I strongly disagree with upvoting trivial, off-topic, duplicate or lazy questions just because the asker is new. This question is basically a mix between "find my typo" and "I don't understand this syntax error" (without even posting the error), with a meta-question of "I'm trying to shoot myself in the foot" - all of these are hardly on topic. IMO one should indicate the error in a comment, maybe downvote, and move on - but certainly not upvote 4 times.

Comment: @l4mpi Well, if you haven't figured it out, one person can only vote _once_, some some people might have agreed that downvoting the hell out of this question was a mistake. Secondly, this guy is such a newbie, that he figured out _yesterday_ that you can put a for loop in a for [loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449476/finding-and-printing-file-name-of-zero-length-files-in-python#comment28860154_19449627). He might not even know what on earth _documentation_ means.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac "He might not even know what on earth documentation means" then he should certainly be given some helpful comments and links to docs/tutorials, but _not_ be rewarded (as in: upvoted) for his ignorance. That's one hell of a slippery slope...

Comment: @l4mpi I agree with you. This should have stayed at a 0, or perhaps increased in up-votes upon improvement. And working on adding documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the regex, you are missing two things:

1. Python does not have a regex type, so you have to wrap it in a string. Use a `raw` string so that the string is passed as-is to the regex compiler, without any escape interpretation
2. The result of the `.read()` call is a byte sequence, not a string. So you need a *byte sequence* regex.

The second one is Python3-specific (and I see that you are using Py3)

Putting all together, just fix the aforementioned line like this:

```
pat = re.compile (rb'<img [^>]*src="([^"]+)')
```

`r` stands for raw and `b` for byte sequence.

Additionally, test on a website that actually embeds images in `<img>` tags, like http://stackoverflow.com. You will not find anything when processing http://google.com

Here we go:

```
Python 3.3.2+
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib.request
>>> import re
>>> website = urllib.request.urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com/')
>>> html = website.read()
>>> pat = re.compile (rb'<img [^>]*src="([^"]+)')
>>> img = pat.findall(html)
>>> img
[b'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png', b'https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmHl0.png', b'https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmHl0.png', b'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png', b'https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QN0y.png', b'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png', b'https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8rHf.png', b'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png', b'http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.gif']
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was close!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `urllib`, I used `requests`, you can download it from [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/). They do the same thing, I just like `requests` better since it has a better API. The regex string is only slightly changed. `\s` is just added in case there are a few whites spaces before the `img` tag. You *were* headed in the right direction. You can find out more about the `re` module [here](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Here is the code

```
import requests
import re

website = requests.get('http://stackoverflow.com//')
html = website.text
pat = re.compile(r'<\s*img [^>]*src="([^"]+)')
img = pat.findall(html)

print img
```

And the output:

```
[u'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png', u'https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8rHf.png', u'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png', u'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ryr18.png', u'https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASf0H.png', u'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png', u'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png', u'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png', u'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ryr18.png', u'https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgvXl.png', u'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png', u'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png', u'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png', u'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png', u'https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QN0y.png', u'http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.gif']
```

Comment: I will add one suggestion. This answer is good. The question would have been valid without any code to retrieve a web page. In the future, it might be worthwhile to make a function that finds what you want from a string or array of bytes. Then the function has only a single concern, finding a list of images.

Answer (score 0):

`re.compile (r'<img [^>]*src="([^"]+)')`

you are missing the quotation marks (single or double) around the pattern

Comment: "and just to be sure it's good to escape quotation marks within the expresion" - what? That's more than wrong in this case...

Comment: agreed, but thanks for catching the missing quotation marks. now my error reads as: 
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Comment: it's a general remark regarding regex. in his case of parsing html he should catch both single and double quotation marks, but that is his job to do

Comment: @mislav do you know what the `r` in front of the string means? "escaping" the quotation marks should only be done if they actually need to be escaped. Your regex matches `\"` instead of just the `"`.

Comment: i'm changing the answer just not do derail someone in the future to just include the remark about the missing quotes. worrying about quotes inside the regex for html is a whole new issue

Comment: @l4mpi so you are saying that it's ok for him to write ```r"<img [^>]*src="([^0"]+)"```?

Comment: @l4mpi since he need to take care of both single and double quotes in html or else he will wind up  with only partital results

Comment: No, I'm saying YOUR REGEX IS WRONG because YOU are using `'` for your real string, meaning the inner `"` DOES NOT NEED TO BE ESCAPED and thus ESCAPING IT IS __WRONG__ because it DOES NOT MATCH THE CORRECT THINGS. Do I need to repeat this with even more capslock or bolding?